# How can I pass build args with a remote image in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to pull a remote image from a private registry. The image's dockerfile contains some args whose values would be populated via docker-compose.yml. For example:

```
version: '3.0'

services:
    api:
        image: remoteApiImage
    web:
        image: remoteWebImage
        build: 
            args:
                baseurl: http://remoteApiImage:80
```

Currently, this does not work as build requires a context. However, if I set a context, it expects a local Dockerfile. Even setting to . without a local Dockerfile will pull the remote image, but the build args are not passed properly.

Is this possible?

Note: I am using Windows Server 2016 containers. Not sure that is relevant to the issue.

Comment: Confused about the question, you pass build args to a build? You're trying to pass build args to an already built image? Do you mean regular `env` variables?

Comment: that would make more sense, but there is this: Note: If your service specifies a build option, variables defined in environment will not be automatically visible during the build. Use the args sub-option of build to define build-time environment variables. 
 https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment

Comment: That doesn't seem related to what you're trying to do. Either you use a pre-built image and pass environment variables to it (if it allows) or if you need to manipulate build args, you'll need to use it's Dockerfile and build the image yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As johnharris85 comment suggests, what you are trying to do is not possible. You cannot pull and image and then rebuild it (without the `Dockerfile`).

If you are trying to specify arguments to an image then you would d this via environment variables. Otherwise, if you have the sources `Dockerfile` for the image, you can use the `ARG` function to specify arguments while rebuilding it yourself.

`build` and `image` in the `docker-compose.yml` context are mutually exclusive.

Comment: That's correct. But note that build & image can be used together: *"If you specify image as well as build, then Compose names the built image with the webapp and optional tag specified in image"* https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build